# getLastKnownLocation returning Null in Android 7+ versions

Tags: android, null, gps, location

I am working on Android application in which I am getting Location. Below code is working fine till Android 6.0 but in Android 7.0 + versions it is giving me null at getLastKnownLocation.

```
try {
            String country_name = null;
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            for (String provider : lm.getAllProviders()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null) {
                    try {
                        //,

                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                            country_name = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            /*if(country_name.equalsIgnoreCase("India")||country_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Pakistan")){*/
                            if(country_name.equalsIgnoreCase("India")){
                                selectedIndia = true;
                            }else{
                                CheckRCRCSuggestion();
                            }

                            syncLocation(location);


                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The problem might not even be the Android version, but instead the device you are testing on. The getLastLocation() method just gets the last known location that the device happens to know. Sometimes the device does not "happen to know" its location and null is returned.

The device doesn't determine its location on its own, but only when some application request the location. So your app is now dependent on other applications requesting location updates.

You can try opening Google Maps on the Android 7 device and then try your own app again. It might then receive a location.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thanks for your comment here. I have tried this one, but still it is not giving me a location. Still it is returning me NULL at getLastKnowLocation method

Answer (score -1):

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

Comment: you might want to add some comments on what you changed; and why this is a solution to the question.

Comment: This is a common "anti-pattern". Calling `requestLocationUpdates()` without a proper location listener implementation is silly. And as it starts an asynchronous operation which may take several seconds (or even tens of seconds) the `getLastKnownLocation()` call right after it still returns `null` on the first call of the `getLocation()` method. Sure, it may start returning locations after a while on subsequent calls.